# Methods of writing LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm perplexed by the below.

I've been using LINQ in my projects using formats such as:

```
var query =     
    from obj_i in set1
    join obj_j in set2 on 
        new { 
          JoinField1 = obj_i.SomeField1,
          JoinField2 = obj_i.SomeField2,
          JoinField3 = obj_i.SomeField3,
          JoinField4 = obj_i.SomeField4
        } 
        equals 
        new { 
          JoinField1 = obj_j.SomeOtherField1,
          JoinField2 = obj_j.SomeOtherField2,
          JoinField3 = obj_j.SomeOtherField3,
          JoinField4 = obj_j.SomeOtherField4
        }
```

But I was recently told that the below is also 'another way' of writing LINQ queries.

```
var query =     
    from obj_i in set1
    join obj_j in set2 on       
    obj_i.SomeField1 = obj_j.SomeOtherField1 and
    obj_i.SomeField2 = obj_j.SomeOtherField2 and
    obj_i.SomeField3 = obj_j.SomeOtherField3 and
    obj_i.SomeField4 = obj_j.SomeOtherField4
```

As I understand, using the single `=` is wrong (especially in the case where by `==` doesn't apply since you need to use `equals`, but also using `and` is wrong, since the correct keyword would be `&&` if you were allowed to use anything but `equals` in this case.

I can understand the use of `&&` and `==` in the where clause, which makes it even more outstanding that the above code can be used, since it doesn't even compile.

Am I missing something?
If so, could you point me to where I can learn of this alternate method of writing LINQ?

Comment: Maybe "they" referred to VB.NET syntax. But you're correct. In C# it's `==` and `&&`. Not `=` and `and`.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen indeed i thought of VB.NET syntax, but even that requires the use of `equals`

Comment: The second is not a valid query, even with the corrections on the operators.  The `join` clause syntax is `join <item> in <collection> on <some object> equals <some object>`.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks, so far, as I expected, this writing style is non-existent and just assumed pseudo code. I will mark answered that which can prove this.

Comment: "could you point me to where I can learn of this alternate method of writing LINQ?" - how about asking the person who recently told you about it?

Comment: @AakashM funny enough his reply was that I need to learn about writing LINQ. What puzzles me is that I've seen it more than twice in the SO community itself.

Comment: I wouldn't put much store by someone who talk in vague terms about code that doesn't compile, but I guess I don't know them. I note that that `and` isn't a C# keyword...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I was recently told that the below is also 'another way' of writing LINQ queries.

No, the second syntax you show is incorrect. Just try it, you'll see that it doesn't compile.

The `join` clause in Linq query comprehension syntax is translated to a call to the [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) extension method. For instance, this query:

```
var query =
    from x in a
    join y in b
    on x.Foo equals y.Bar
    select Baz(x, y);
```

Is translated to:

```
var query = a.Join(b, x => x.Foo, y => y.Foo, (x, y) => Baz(x, y));
```

So you can see that the parts on the left and right of `equals` correspond to different parameters of the `Join` method: the left part selects the join key for the first source, and the right part selects the key for the second source. These keys are then matched against each other to perform the join. This is the important part: the `on` clause doesn't specify a free-form join condition, it specifies how to extract the join key on each side. So the left and right key selectors *have* to be clearly separated; the second syntax you show can't work, because there's no way to extract full key information for either source: the join could only be performed by evaluating the join condition for each `(x, y)`, which is an `O(n²)` operation instead of a (roughly) `O(n)` operation.

However, sometimes you need more flexibility than what an equi-join can give; in that case you can use a cross-join and filter the results:

```
var query =
    from x in a
    from y in b
    where x.Foo == y.Bar
    select Baz(x, y);
```

Or in your case:

```
var query =     
    from obj_i in set1
    from obj_j in set2
    where obj_i.SomeField1 == obj_j.SomeOtherField1
    &&    obj_i.SomeField2 == obj_j.SomeOtherField2
    &&    obj_i.SomeField3 == obj_j.SomeOtherField3
    &&    obj_i.SomeField4 == obj_j.SomeOtherField4;
```

Comment: thanks, I'm aware it doesn't compile, which is why I was almost going to believe that they were referencing a LINQ library from Mars. Nice answer, makes me wonder how come VB.NET can make use of the `equals` and the `and` in a `join`.

Comment: i just compiled and ran the below in VB.NET and works fine.

Dim query = From one In setones
                    Join two In settwos
                    On one.ID Equals two.ID And one.Name Equals two.ContactName

Comment: @ericosg, that's weird, I tried it too and it just said "syntax error"... Anyway, if it's correct, I guess the compiler just groups together the keys of each side.

Comment: quite odd. I'm using VS 2010 btw. Works even in runtime. cheers

Comment: @ericosg, I just tried again, I had made a mistake by putting a line break where it didn't belong... I'm always having trouble with the VB syntax ;). So it does work, and results in the same expression as `Dim query = From one In setones Join two In settwos On New With { one.ID, one.Name } Equals New With { two.ID, .Name = two.ContactName }`